# NPM & Docker Build

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to "build" my npm build and create a docker image with it. That means I need a docker image that is able to a) run npm and b) run docker.
Currently I struggle in finding / creating such a docker image. How can I solve my problem?
Thanks!

**Edit:**
I managed to have a combined container, but my build is not able to find a running docker instance:
`Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/build?cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&memory=0&memswap=0&rm=1&t=registry.gitlab.com%2Ftss-repocar%2Fapp&ulimits=null: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/images/registry.gitlab.com/tss-repocar/app/push?tag=: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?`

Comment: If you're thinking of using docker-in-docker then have a read of this: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Answer (score 0):

Use Packer. You run commands in Packer to do all of your NPM setup, and it will spit out a Docker container.

Here is packer 
https://www.packer.io/docs/

And then I found this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-packer

Answer (score 0):

To build docker images your build container must have access to `/var/run/docker.sock` (or you have to use Docker in Docker).

Assuming you have your `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` in a Docker Container itself, change `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` to look like this:

`volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]`